# two different length variables one subject to another

Tags: r

I would like to reference the two data frames x and y below providing the range to get elements to provide to the function below first x takes all the y elements and so forth as to obtain the indexed result of z as in the same format as in z[1:3] ... I know I could use expand.grid in a lapply function as to reference them easily and roll over the whole row length. However this method is not adequate for the example as I would like to keep the list structure of z as the output.

```
# I have a list of elements and its sequences: 

z  <- list ( c( 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0 ), c( 5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4 ) )  
x  <- c( 1,2 )
y  <- c( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ) 
Sx <- seq(x)
Sy <- seq(y)

# were sequential data frames are made as to attempt to index them
sequentially to z:

addbeg <- 0
addend <- length ( x )
C      <-  c( addbeg , seq ( addend ) )
newpairs0 <- cbind ( C[-length(C)] , C[-1] )

addbeg <- 0
addend <- length( y )
D      <-  c( addbeg , seq(addend ) )  
newpairs1 <- cbind ( D[-length(D)] , D[-1] )

# Though doing this via a mapply function where to index the two prior results but can not figure it out.     

# The desired output from a unespecied function is: 


[[1]]
[1] 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

[[2]]
[1] 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: PLease tell us the actual problem you're trying to solve, not the way you want to go at it.  There's no magical way to create `N` results out of ` M<N` operations, so you have to have a reason for re-using or re-mapping your input data.

Comment: I do the reason is to preserve the format  to find out where a certain result occurred. however I see that I will have to use expand grid and then reform the data back as to be able to identify it.